# Liferay 7 CE - Osgi module (liferay mvc portlet) not load javascript files

Tags: javascript, osgi, portlet, liferay-7

I created a new liferay osgi module.
My controller has the following tag :

```
@Component(
immediate = true,
property = {
    "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=Bla Modules",
    "com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=true",
    "javax.portlet.display-name=EventCalendar",
    "javax.portlet.init-param.template-path=/",
    "javax.portlet.expiration-cache=0",
    "com.liferay.portlet.footer-portlet-javascript=fullcalendar_year.js,/js/custom/main.js",
    "com.liferay.portlet.header-portlet-css=/css/fullcalendar_year.css,/css/fullcalendar.css",
    "javax.portlet.init-param.view-template=/view.jsp",
    "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language",
    "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=administrator,power-user,user"
},
service = Portlet.class
```

However the property

> com.liferay.portlet.footer-portlet-javascript

is not loading all js files, it only loades the files if only one is called, if it is more than one nothing is loaded.

Is this a bug or i am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Finally i found the solution.
It must be declared in separate lines.

```
property = {
    "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=XXXXAA Modules",
    "com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=true",
    "javax.portlet.display-name=XXXXAA",
    "javax.portlet.init-param.template-path=/",
    "javax.portlet.expiration-cache=0",
    "com.liferay.portlet.footer-portlet-javascript=/js/moment.min.js",
    "com.liferay.portlet.footer-portlet-javascript=/js/fullcalendar_year.js",
    "com.liferay.portlet.footer-portlet-javascript=/js/calendarLanguages/pt.js",
    "com.liferay.portlet.footer-portlet-javascript=/js/custom/main.js",
    "com.liferay.portlet.header-portlet-css=/css/fullcalendar_year.css,/css/fullcalendar.css",
    "javax.portlet.init-param.view-template=/view.jsp",
    "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language",
    "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=administrator,power-user,user"
}
```

Comment: is it possible to send the dynamical "js or css"  path using regular expression  like the below


"com.liferay.portlet.footer-portlet-javascript=/js/main.[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{5}[a-zA-Z]{1}\\d{1}.chunk.js",